# Visual Studio code Debugger won’t start on my Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

I have a very simple program written but when I click start on the Visual Studio debugger nothing happens!  Sorry total noob here.  Working with python 3.6.5 32 bit for Windows.  The program runs from the terminal just fine.

```
def main():  
  print ("hello world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":  
  main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you installed [Visual Studio Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)? If not, refer to this post to get the Python environment in Visual Studio https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of one of the [existing 9,000 questions on Visual Studio debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=starting+visual+studio+debugger). Try those, and also Visual Studio help sites and tutorials.

Comment: Can we clean up/ improve/ canonicalize/ close [how to debug python in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988796/how-to-debug-python-in-visual-studio), [How to start debugging Python 3.6 in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273900/how-to-start-debugging-python-3-6-in-visual-studio-code) etc?

Comment: Thanks for the help davedwards, I did have the python extension installed sorry I didn’t mention that.  Smci I looked through the first 100 or so, maybe you could give me some advice on how to narrow the options.

Comment: @Jaydubs, Do you use the VS IDE or VS code? They are two different tools. If you use the VS IDE like the VS 2017, as you said that you create a simple Python project, could you share the code in your issue? Not debug your app, how about running it with Ctrl+F5 or debug it with a breakpoint? If you get any error messages in the Output or Error list window, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Well i can't get it to format correctly. :/  i tried the double space for a line break and that's not working for me.

def main():  
  print ("hello world!")  
    
if __name__ == "__main__":  
  main()

Comment: I used the VS IDE.  Ctrl F5 doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: ok, i figured out how to add the code to my original post.  please see above.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across the same issue in VS Code (I think) in that I can run a one line python file from the terminal and it will work as expected:

```
python HelloWorld.py
```

However when I try to run it in the debugger nothing happens other than the Debug toolbar briefly appearing. I got more suspicious having put a junk console entry in launch.json and it didn't cause any errors.

My problem was that the training instructions I'm following told me to set the following for my workspace settings so it would use the specific python executable in my virtual environment:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "env\\Scripts\\python"
}
```

Once I changed the last part of that path to **python.exe**, everything worked as expected. Hopefully you can try a similar resolution in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with all ide programs not just VS.code the problem is when installing python you didn't allow different ide environments to use python and its only executable from windows terminal what you need to do is delete python and VS code completely then again install python 3.x and in the first page of installation check the "Add python to path" box its a must if you want to use something other than windows terminal to code. after reinstalling the python now reset your device and install VS code again and that's it. problem solved